# Using JSON In Data Services with WSO2 Enterprice Integrator

Tags: json, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Product Version: WSO2-EI-6.3

I have created a data service to retrieve data as a JSON like below format.

```
{
   "Employees":{
      "Employee":[
         {
            "EmployeeNumber":"1"
         },
         {
            "EmployeeNumber":"2"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Find below the sequence used to create the data service in EI.

```
<data name="RDBMSDataService" transports="http https local">
   <config enableOData="false" id="DataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
      <property name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Employees</property>
      <property name="username">root</property>
      <property name="password">1234</property>
   </config>
   <query id="SelectAllEmployees" useConfig="DataSource">
      <sql>select EmployeeNumber from Employees</sql>
      <result outputType="json">{&#xd;"Employees":{&#xd;"Employee":[&#xd;{&#xd;"EmployeeNumber":"$EmployeeNumber"&#xd;}&#xd;]&#xd;}&#xd;}</result>
   </query>
   <operation name="AllEmployees">
      <call-query href="SelectAllEmployees"/>
   </operation>
</data>
```

But Still, it gives the XML mapped output as below.

```
<Employees xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/SelectAllEmployees">
   <Employee>
      <EmployeeNumber>1</EmployeeNumber>
   </Employee>
   <Employee>
      <EmployeeNumber>2</EmployeeNumber>
   </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have I been working on it days ago?
What I suggest you to do is. In your client side pass the following header:

'Accept':'application/json'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyhBo.png)

Then:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfcgr.png)